# a select attribute created via installer script doesn't show the options as given

Tags: magento-1.8

I am trying to create a product attribute through module (custom) install via installer script. here is my code:

```
$installerx = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup();

$installerx->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'osn_allowed', array(
    'group' => 'General',
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'Enable Notification',
    'input' => 'select',
    'option' => array(
        'value' => array( 
            '1' => array( 'Yes' ),
            '2' => array( 'No' ),
        )
    ),
    'class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => '',
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'unique' => false,
    'apply_to' => '',
    'is_configurable' => false
));
```

the attribute does create but not with required options as was given rather (using firebug) it shows like this:

```
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="126">No</option>
```

i want it to be like:

```
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
```

how can i achieve this by updating/correcting the installer code above?

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use boolean type, that comes up with value of "1/0" with lables "Yes/No".
here is the code

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'is_enabled', array(
                 'group'    => 'Any Group',
                 'label'    => 'Any Label',          
                 'type' => 'int',
                 'input'    => 'boolean',                  
                 'visible'  => true,
                 'required' => false,
                 'position' => 21,
                 'global'   => 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL',
         'note'     => "select yes no"
    ));


  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="0">No</option>
```

Comment: yes this worked changing the input type to boolean and removing the option. its even better.

Comment: When I use this I get the exception `Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Boolean' not found`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use default Magento's **boolean** type of the attribute:

```
$installerx->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'osn_allowed', array(
    'group' => 'General'
    'type' => 'int',
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'input' => 'select',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true
));
```

And  you should get values 0 and 1 automatically.

Comment: Elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your script change the following part of code as below.

```
. . . . 

 'option' => 
  array (
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Please select',
      1 => 'Yes',
      2 => 'No',
    ),
  ),

 . . . . .
```

Comment: i did do that. still nothing works. i think it has something to do with the type.

Comment: Thank you.. This helped me a lot.. Initially I am trying with out "0=>Please Select".. So only it is not creating.. Now it works fine..

Comment: @ Pavan Kumar: Glad to hear that this was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want create the yes/no dropdown attribute please this code. Please check my tutorial for step by step explanation.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/add-custom-attribute-dropdown-category-section-magento/

```
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'featured_product', array(
'group'         => 'General Information',
'input'         => 'select',
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Featured Product',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
));
```