# How to display the value of drop down whether it is set to yes/no from dopbox in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I created a custom attribute using installer as given below: . This attribute is created inside group Customer Product. I tried to accessed the value of dropdown but could not access it. How could I access the value from dropdown. Please suggest.

```
 <?php
    $installer = $this;
    /* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
    $installer->startSetup();
    $attrCode = 'customer_product';
    $attrGroupName = 'Customer Product';
    $attrLabel = 'Customer Product';
    $attrNote = 'Customer Note';
    $objCatalogEavSetup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_mysql4_setup', 'core_setup');
    $attrIdTest = $objCatalogEavSetup->getAttributeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCode);

    if ($attrIdTest === false) {
        $objCatalogEavSetup->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCode, array(
            'group' => $attrGroupName,
            'sort_order' => 7,
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => $attrLabel,
            'note' => $attrNote,
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '0',
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'is_configurable' => false,
            'used_for_promo_rules' => true
        ));
    }
    $installer->endSetup();
    ?>
```

Then I coded inside my theme in phtml to display the product only if customer product is set to yes. But its not working

```
<?php
 // $attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','test');
 // echo $attribute_value = $attributeModel->getStoreLabel($storeId);
  $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*') ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')->setPageSize(10);
  foreach($products as $product):
   // echo $product->getSku();
     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
     $attribute_value = $_product->getAttributeText('customer_product');
     if($attribute_value == 'Yes')
      {
       ?>

        <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200); ?>">
       <?php
       ?>
        <br />
       <!--  <center> -->
       <?php
       echo $product->getName().'<br />';
       echo $product->getPrice();
       ?>
       <!--  </center> -->
       <?php
      }
  endforeach;
?>
```

What's wrong with  my code?

Comment: check if the attribute is assigned to attribute group of the product

Comment: yes it is assigned to the attribute group. What should I change in the code please suggest @Piyush

Comment: Is it a dropdown field with Yes/No option or a textbox?

Comment: if it is yes/no type then refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12139/45103

Answer (score 0):

After creating product attribute, you need to reindex from admin panel. Navigate to System > Index Management and reindex all. Also flush cache from Cache Management.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create attribute using below script (Add your configuration)

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'customer_product', array(
                 'group'    => 'Any Group',
                 'label'    => 'Any Label',          
                 'type' => 'int',
                 'input'    => 'boolean',                  
                 'visible'  => true,
                 'required' => false,
                 'global'   => 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL',
         'note'     => "select yes no"
));
```

Retrieve value by

```
$product->getData('customer_product');
```